# How to sort associated table data?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I've to show the has one relation table data in the listing. I'm using CakePHP pagination and search functionality for the listing view. All the rest of the functionality is working fine, but I'm not able to give the sort functionality for the related table field.

I'm using

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('First Name','Enrollment.first_name');?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Last Name','Enrollment.last_name');?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Product','Product.name');?></th>
```

But sorting on product is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('First Name','Enrollment.first_name');?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Last Name','Enrollment.last_name');?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Product','Product.name');?></th>
```

.....

```
<td>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($YOURVAR['Enrollment']['first_name'], array('controller' => 'enrollments', 'action' => 'view', $YOURVAR['Enrollment']['id'])); ?>
</td>
<td>
  <?php echo $this->Html->link($YOURVAR['Enrollment']['title'], array('controller' => 'enrollments', 'action' => 'view', $YOURVAR['Enrollment']['id'])); ?>
</td>
<td>

  // Checkout this line that you change the line as following
  <?php echo $this->Html->link($YOURVAR['Product']['name'], array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view', $YOURVAR['Product']['id'])); ?>
</td>
```